# PHP How to detect if rewrite module is installed on IIS

Tags: php, apache, iis, module, url-rewriting

I a writing an application in PHP to be hosted on a web server. I don't know whether the web server is IIS or Apache. I don't know whether the appropriate rewrite modules is installed or not. I need to detect the web server, and detect whether the module is installed and then execute code accordingly. So far, I know how to detect whether the server is IIS or Apache, and have a reasonably good way of detecting the module on Apache:

My .htaccess file is:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    SetEnv HTTP_MOD_REWRITE On
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^.*$ ./index.php
</IfModule>
```

And I can detect apache and the module this way:

```
$mod_rewrite=false;
if(strpos(strtolower($_SERVER['SERVER_SOFTWARE']),'apache')!==false){
    if(function_exists('apache_get_modules')){
        $modules=apache_get_modules();
        $mod_rewrite=in_array('mod_rewrite',$modules);
    }
    else{
        $mod_rewrite=getenv('HTTP_MOD_REWRITE')=='On'?true:false;
    }
}
```

I can detect IIS like this:

```
if(strpos(strtolower($_SERVER['SERVER_SOFTWARE']),'microsoft-iis')!==false){
    ...
}
```

And I can achieve the same rewrite as what's happening in Apache but on IIS by putting this in the IIS web.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--web.config url rewrite-->
<configuration> 
  <system.webServer>
      <rewrite>
          <rules>
              <rule name="Redirect To Index" stopProcessing="true">
                  <match url=".*" />
                  <conditions>
                      <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                      <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                  </conditions>
                  <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.php" />
              </rule>
          </rules>
      </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

But I don't know how to detect in PHP if the rewrite module is correctly installed and working. Is there a way in PHP to do this?

I'm open to suggestions about using PHP to check if a particulcar URL returns a known string if the rewrite is working correctly. For example, if I used PHP to query `http://example.com/something` and it actually returned the contents on `http://example.com/test.html` (the content being known), then that would show to rewrite module is working. If it's not, the request would return a 404 not found error.

But how do I get PHP to query a URL that's on the same server? Do I query `localhost` ? For example,

```
$content=file_get_contents('http://localhost/something');
if($content=='success'){
    // works!
}
else if( /* Error 404 */ ){
    // rewrite not working
}
```

Or will the server's domain name work from a local script?